# How i can writte this in php for strings and no give me error

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$array_names=array("phone","car","house");
```

**I have this string:** `$phone_[$jr]`

But the string with string called phone it's a name for value, i want use other names for get values, by this it´s necessary write using as this :

```
${$phone}
```

The problem it´s i need use other thing more in this string :

```
${$phone}_[$jr]
```

**And this give me error**

I see the problem it´s with "_" but i need use, my question it´s about how i need writte right for works

> ${$phone}_[$jr]

**In other cases i need use :**

```
${$house}_[$jr]
```

Etc, .....

**Thank´s**

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to explain to us. Maybe is you use Google translate andwrite the question in your language, then copy the English translation into your question, it would help

Comment: The question it´s very simple, i need write this : ${$phone}_[$jr], but give me error only i need know how writte the same expression if i put ${$phone}[$jr] it´s right but if i put with "_" no works and i need use this because the string no array, only string,

Comment: Why do you need to put the `_` between your variables?

Comment: Do you mean `${$phone} . '_' . [$jr];`

Comment: Yes i need that right the original string it´s $phone_[$jr], but phone  the word phone change and for take the value i need use ${$phone}, and no works as the original string, it´s only that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a scenario like this:

```
// this is the array you are trying to access dynamically
$bar_ = [];

// this will hold the first part of the variable name
$phone = 'bar';

// and this is how you would build the string which is the full name of the array
// You can then use it to access one of its elements.
${$phone.'_'}[1] = 'f';
```

Comment: Thank´s perfect works for me , thank´s a lot for understand me, regards

Comment: I would also recommend to use an associative array instead of dynamic variable names. It would make your life much easier and help static analysers to understand your code.